# C# Tcp Server client Disconnecting problems

Tags: c#, sockets, tcpclient, tcplistener

Whenever a client Disconnects, the server crashes. Here's the code for the server

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace C_Sharp_Testting
{
class Server
{

    private static TcpListener tcpListener;
    private static List<TcpClient> tcpClientsList = new List<TcpClient>();


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 1234);
        tcpListener.Start();

        Console.WriteLine("Server started");

        while (true)
        {
            TcpClient tcpClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
            tcpClientsList.Add(tcpClient);

            Thread thread = new Thread(ClientListener);
            thread.Start(tcpClient);


        }
    }

    public static void ClientListener(object obj)
    {
        TcpClient tcpClient = (TcpClient)obj;
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(tcpClient.GetStream());

        Console.WriteLine("Client connected");

        while (true)
        {
            string message = reader.ReadLine();
            BroadCast(message, tcpClient);
            Console.WriteLine(">>> "+message);

        }

    }

    public static void BroadCast(string msg, TcpClient excludeClient)
    {
        foreach (TcpClient client in tcpClientsList)
        {
            if (client != excludeClient)
            {
                StreamWriter sWriter = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
                sWriter.WriteLine(">>> "+msg);
                sWriter.Flush();



            }


        }


    }


}
}
```

I've already tried closing the reader and tcpClient, but none of them worked.

Answer (score 1):

The thing that initially hits me is that you have not added any error handling to this code.
When you try to read from a disconnected socket, you will encounter an exception, which will crash your application.

You add a try and catch statement to the ClientListener method, to allow each Socket the ability to manage and handle its own errors.
This means you will be able to detect disconnects and handle them gracefully.

Consider implementing events.
Create an event called OnDisconnect, and then add your own handler to the event to remove the disconnected client from the list of clients.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Event is triggered when the peer is disconnecting
    /// </summary>
    public event DisconnectHandler OnDisconnect;
    public delegate void DisconnectHandler(Peer p);
```

This is an extension class

```
static class SocketExtensions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Extension method to tell if the Socket REALLY is closed
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="socket"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static bool IsConnected(this Socket socket)
        {
            try
            {
                return !(socket.Poll(1, SelectMode.SelectRead) && socket.Available == 0);
            }
            catch (SocketException) { return false; }
        }
    }
```

Pseudocode below:

```
if (PeerStream.CanRead)
                {
                    //networkStream.Read(byteLen, 0, 8)
                    byte[] byteLen = new byte[8];
                    if (_client.Client.IsConnected() == false)
                    {
                        //Fire Disconnect event
                        if (OnDisconnect != null)
                        {
                            disconnected = true;
                            OnDisconnect(this);
                            return null;
                        }
                    }
                    while (len == 0)
                    {
                        PeerStream.Read(byteLen, 0, 8);

                        len = BitConverter.ToInt32(byteLen, 0);
                    }
                    data = new byte[len];

                    PeerStream.Read(data, receivedDataLength, len);

                    return data;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many things wrong with your code. At a guess, I would say the primary reason for the crash is that you are adding TcpClients to a list **but never removing them**. That means regardless of client disconnects, your code still tries to access every TcpClient that ever connected.

On top of that, the code is inherently thread-unsafe. You are adding items to a list in one thread while using a foreach loop to iterate over the list at the same time in a different thread - this will almost certainly result in an exception being thrown.

Lastly, there's no try-catch blocks. If your code is crashing, a simple improvement is to wrap the problem areas with try-catch blocks and handle/log/examine the exceptions when they occur.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any code to detect that any of the clients have closed its connection. You keep doing reader.Readline. But that won't work. You should use a networkstream instead and check for receiving 0 bytes which indicates the client has closed its end of the connection. It is either this or using exceptionhandling. But receiving 0 bytes is not really an error condition. IMHO you should not use exceptions to capture normal logic flow but real errors. This does not mean you don't have to wrap everything in a try catch block though. You still have to do that too.

from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.read(v=vs.110).aspx:

> This method reads data into the buffer parameter and returns the number of bytes successfully read. If no data is available for reading, the Read method returns 0. The Read operation reads as much data as is available, up to the number of bytes specified by the size parameter. If the remote host shuts down the connection, and all available data has been received, the Read method completes immediately and return zero bytes.'

When a client disconnects and detected properly you can do all that is needed to make it work properly, like removing it from the list, letting the thread terminate and so on.

Note also that the tcpClientsList  needs some kind of semaphore protection otherwise multiple threads are accessing this same list which can lead to strange behavior that happens only now and then.